# What is L2TP connection in ZTE 670L router and how to make it work?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

My ISP has provided me ZTE 670L GPON router.  The router has an option L2TP VPN Connection.
I have L2TP account on an Internet server. They have provided me  Servername, Userid, Password, Preshared key.

From my Windows 10 laptop, I can easily connect to this VPN server by creating L2TP connection. However when I enter the values in L2TP connection in ZTE 670L router the status shows Disconnected.  Auth type is Auto, PAP & CHAP, all 3 give same Disconnected status.

I guess router page does not have provision for pre-shared key? See the screenshot. Is this the reason it shows Disconnected in Status and how does it actually work in this router?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure what pre-shared key you might be referring to. L2TP, which is not encrypted, only specifies PAP and CHAP. Furthermore, the setting you’re looking at appears to be for WAN connections, not for (outgoing) VPN.

Answer (score 2):

> I have L2TP account on an Internet server. They have provided me Servername, Userid, Password, Preshared key.

Sounds like you actually have an **L2TP-over-IPsec** account, where the username and password are for L2TP while the preshared key is for IPsec (IKEv1) encryption.

L2TP/IPsec is a very common combination for VPNs (due to Windows having built-in support for it) but it's not the same as "plain" L2TP; your router won't be able to actually talk to the L2TP server unless it has established an IPsec association first.

I suspect that the L2TP support in your router is not meant to be used with external VPN services, but instead only for connecting to your own ISP (in the same way that many ISPs require PPPoE).

Comment: I agree, since win10 doesn't even have a L2TP connection not over IPsec, or does it?